# EXTRN function call issue is there a way to know what is causing it?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

> /* function supposed to allocate memory for in array and fill it (half with help of the function ;received in call and the other half with the help of external function rand*?
>
> defining variables

```
.MODEL LARGE
.DATA 
Parr DW ?
ParrS DW ?
len DW ?
getnum DW ?
getnumS DW ?
two DW 2
```

> declaring functions

```
.code 
.386
PUBLIC _initarr 
EXTRN _rand:NEAR
EXTRN _malloc:NEAR
_initarr PROC FAR
```

> saving non general registers in stack & extracting received values and addresses sent by c call int  >initarr(int**arr, int n, int (*initfunc)(int));

```
PUSH BP
MOV BP,SP 
PUSH SI
PUSH DI
PUSH ES
MOV AX,[BP+6]

MOV Parr,AX
MOV AX,[BP+8]
MOV ParrS,AX
MOV AX,[BP+10]
MOV len,AX
MOV AX,[BP+12]
MOV getnum,AX
MOV AX,[BP+14]
MOV getnumS,AX
```

> getting parameter ready to send to malloc, calling malloc & checking allocation success

```
MOV AX,len 
MUL two
PUSH AX ;sending parameter to malloc
CALL _malloc 
ADD SP,2
CMP AX,0
JZ cont 
MOV ES,ParrS
MOV SI,Parr
MOV [ES:SI],AX ;setting address returned by malloc in address sent by function call

cont:
POP ES ;retrieving old registers from stack
POP DI
POP SI
POP BP
RET ;return
_initarr ENDP
END
```

> getting a "fixup overlow" error , checked the syntax a couple times it's probably not that, tried searching it online but it can be caused by many different reasons, any help?
>
> Error message: "Fixup overflow at init_TEXT:002D, target = _malloc in module init.ASM
>
> Fixup overflow at init_TEXT:007B, target = _rand in module init.ASM

[image: a screenshot of the compiling error]

Comment: You define `_rand` and `_malloc` as `NEAR`, meaning they are expected to be within the same segment as the calling code. But apparently they are not. What is your [memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model)?

Comment: thank you very much it worked, i'm new to assembly so sometimes i get stuck with basic stuff, appreciate your fast response 
"all i had to do is change my memory model from large to small"

Answer (score 0):

i had to change my memory model from large to small in order to fix the issue, i believe it's possible to define the external functions as  far instead, i tried it yet didn't work for some reason.